# Can't identify the following error: TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)

Tags: python, kivy, mobile-application

I'm very new to programing, and i'm currently following a video to develop an app for a project. I can't seem to understand what is causing the error below.

```
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

The code is as follow; (1st file)

```
class MainApp(App):
    my_friend_id = 1
    def build(self):
        return GUI

    def on_start(self):
        # get database data
        result = requests.get("https://wearable-balance-belt1-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/" + str(self.my_friend_id) +".json")
        data = json.loads(result.content.decode())
        # get and update avatar
        avatar_image = self.root.ids['home_screen'].ids['avatar_image']
        avatar_image.source = "icons/" + data['avatar']

        banner_grid = self.root.ids['home_screen'].ids['banner_grid']
        workouts = data['workouts'][1:]
        for workout in workouts:
            W = WorkoutBanner(workout_image=workout['workout_image'], description=workout['description'])
            banner_grid.add_widget(W)


    def change_screen(self, screen_name):
        # get the screen manager from the kv file
        screen_manager = self.root.ids['screen_manager']
        screen_manager.current = screen_name
        # screen_manager = self.root.ids


MainApp().run()
```

And the second file;

```
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class WorkoutBanner(GridLayout):
    rows = 1

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WorkoutBanner, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        #left floatlayout
        left = FloatLayout()
        left_image = Image(source="icons/" + kwargs['workout_image'], size_hint=(1, .8), pos_hint={"top": 1, "left": 1})
        left_label = Label(text=kwargs['description'], size_hint=(1, .2), post_hint={"top": .2, "left": 1})
        left.add_widget(left_image)
        left.add_widget(left_label)

        self.add_widget(left)
```

Any help that I can get will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

That error is typically due to unexpected arguments being passed to the base (`object` class) `__init__()` method. In your case, the `workout_image` and `description` key word arguments are getting passed to the super class and eventually to the `object` class. You can correct that by using `kwargs.pop()` to remove those arguments before calling `super` in your `__init__()` method of `WorkoutBanner`. An even easier way is to define properties for those two arguments and let kivy handle saving and removing them from the `kwargs`, like this:

```
class WorkoutBanner(GridLayout):
    rows = 1
    workout_image = StringProperty('')
    description = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WorkoutBanner, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        #left floatlayout
        left = FloatLayout()
        left_image = Image(source="icons/" + self.workout_image, size_hint=(1, .8), pos_hint={"top": 1, "left": 1})
        left_label = Label(text=self.description, size_hint=(1, .2), pos_hint={"top": .2, "left": 1})
        left.add_widget(left_image)
        left.add_widget(left_label)

        self.add_widget(left)
```